# Jquery UI Dialog Modal Error ON IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

On form post back inside jquery-ui dialog modal.I am getting below error.

> Unhandled exception at line 1, column 165031 in http://localhost:61892/bundles/jqueryUI?v=ZtBSbUDKlnEJoTEt91W1Sw3Wm7_cMVUFkutTVjnNqLk1
>
> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference

please help me that what browser wants to hint with this error.

Comment: You need to post the code you're using.